# OUT/IN OUT parameters in PL/SQL function

Tags: sql, oracle, function, stored-procedures, plsql

as far as I understood it, it is only possible to have OUT or IN OUT parameters for procedures, not functions. However, when defining a user-defined aggregate function, I have found this signature:

```
member FUNCTION ODCIAggregateIterate(self IN OUT DeviationImpl,
value IN NUMBER) RETURN NUMBER
```

This seems to be a function, however, it has an IN OUT parameter. Could somebody explain me why is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no such restrictions. Functions can have OUT or IN OUT parameters.

However, Oracle recommends against using them.

OUT and IN OUT parameters prevent a function from being used from plain SQL, marked as a DETERMINISTIC function or used as a result-cached function. So these type of parameters are mainly a problem if you want to use the function in a SQL query.

Your example is even more specific: it's a member function, not a global function.

Comment: Ok, I was confused about it, because usually the definition was that a procedure can return 0..* values (via these OUT parameters) whereas function can return only 1 value via RETURN, but then I saw the example I posted. Anyway, thanks for your answer!